# icu-config not works but already installed

Tags: ubuntu, icu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

my question is simple. icu-config does not work.
but icu-devtools is already installed in my system.

this is my terminal screen

```
$ icu-config
The program 'icu-config' is currently not installed. To run 'icu-config' please ask your administrator to install the package 'icu-devtools'

$ sudo apt-get install icu-devtools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
icu-devtools is already the newest version (65.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 67 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but on Ubuntu 22.04. I found that icu-config was installed as a snap package and not in a globally accessible folder. What worked for me was to locate the file `locate icu-config` which returned me `/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/bin/icu-config`. Then I did a symlink to /usr/bin: `ln -s /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/bin/icu-config /usr/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

`65.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` is not ubuntu 16.04's 'normal' ICU package.  I found that [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+build/18742140](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+build/18742140) was built with `--disable-icu-config` which … disables icu-config!

Try using `pkg-config` instead with the names as given here: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/howtouseicu.html#c-makefiles  (icu-uc and icu-i18n).  If I knew about pkg-config, and it was widely propagated enough, I wouldn't have written icu-config! icu-config is now deprecated, and there is more detail about that in that same URL.